# PHP permission error on writing to a file in Linux CentOS

Tags: php, linux, centos

I have installed linux centos 7 on a VmWare in Windows.

There are two users in the linux: `root, sample`

I have created a laravel project with user "sample" (logged in as `sample`), but when I try to run the project with user root (logged in as `root`), it throws a permission error that cannot write to the file (`file_put_content()`). I have tried

```
chmod 777 /var/www/html/laravel
```

Or even I have tried to change the permission of the write-access of the file to root using right-click->properties->permission, but to no avail.

The only possible solution has been to delete the file and re-create it with user root. Now, what is the solution? I though user `root` is privileged to do anything. But it seems it is not the case. What is the solution? How should change this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/laravel/  ,-R is recursive

Comment: Are you getting the error making a Web request? If so it means that the Web server user needs permissions. I know that laravel needs write permissions on app/storage/ directory

Comment: Yes and the problem is for storage. I access it with Zend Server and I wonder how should I enable zend to be able to access (or PHP)

Comment: Did you try putting a backslash at the end? chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/laravel/ and then do a ls -la in that app directory to see the permissions?